# Progress forwards and backwards through table

Tags: lua, lua-table

first time here on Stack Overflow but definitely have found a lot of useful information here!

Currently I'm trying to figure out how to select the next item, or previous item in a table based on the current selection.

My current table is as follows:

```
maleSkins = { 7,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,32,33,34,35,
        36,37,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,51,52,57,58,59,60,61,66,67,72,73,80,82,83,
        84,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,
        112,113,114,115,116,117,118,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,132,
        133,134,135,136,137,142,143,144,146,147,153,154,156,159,160,161,162,
        168,170,173,174,175,176,177,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,
        189,200,202,203,204,206,210,212,213,217,220,221,222,223,227,228,229,
        230,234,235,236,239,240,241,242,247,248,249,250,252,254,258,259,260,261,262 }

femaleSkins = { 9,10,11,12,13,31,38,39,40,41,53,54,55,56,69,76,77,88,89,90,91,92,
        93,129,130,131,138,139,140,141,145,148,151,152,157,190,191,192,193,195,
        196,197,198,199,201,207,211,214,215,216,218,219,224,225,226,232,233,237,238,243,244,245,246,251,256,257 }
```

The default selection is "7" in the maleSkins table, and I will use the femaleSkins table when they choose "female" for their gender.

Currently my function call looks like this

```
function selSkin(button,state)
if button ~= "left" and state ~= "up" then
    return
end
if source == createChar.maleButt then
    femaleSkin = false
    maleSkin = true
elseif source == createChar.femaleButt then
    maleSkin = false
    femaleSkin = true
end
if source == createChar.nextSkin then
    if maleSkin == true then
        newModel = table.concat(maleSkins,)
    elseif femaleSkin == true then
    end
elseif source == createChar.prevSkin then
    if maleSkin == true then
    elseif femaleSkin == true then
    end
end
end
```

So, inside the "createChar.nextSkin" and "createChar.prevSkin" is where I'm trying to sort through the table based on the current skin, but I'm unsure of how to proceed.

I would love if someone could give me the building blocks to do this, and I will build the rest myself!

(Side note: Predefined variables I will be using to make this happen)

```
maleSkin = true
femaleSkin = true
curSkin = 7
newModel = nil
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all welcome to stack overflow :)

A small thing I noticed: you have two variables to store if the character is male or female. This allows for 4 combinations, 2 of which make no sense. You could just as well only use one variable, say, `maleSkin` and when it's false, then you use the female skin instead. Alternatively, you could just do `skinType = 'male'` and `skinType = 'female'` (Lua interns strings, so this is just as fast as comparing integers)

now, unless you plan to have a few millions of skins or more, you can just iterate through the table to find the current skin and then use the previous one.

```
function skinOffset(skin, skinList, offset)
  for i,current_skin in ipairs(skinList) do
    if current_skin == skin then
      return skinList[i + offset]
    else
  end
end
```

Now, to get the next skin you can do `skinOffset(curSkin, maleSkins, 1)` and for the previous one `skinOffset(curSkin, femaleSkins, -1)`.

Comment: Hey so I definitely appreciate the feedback on the variables, it made sense in my mind to have broken variables for both genders, but I definitely see now how I can tweak that down to one. Using your skinOffset, would that function look for the end of the table, and go back through to the start? Or would I need to put a check in place and have it reset if it reached the end of either table?

Comment: You'd have to tweak that to wrap around, but that could be done easily by turning `i` into [`(i-1) % #skinList + 1)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) when indexing `skinList`

Answer (score 0):

Additionally save the table index in a global var.
There are several ways, for instance `skinIndex = 1`, your code could look like this:

```
if source == createChar.nextSkin then
  newModel = maleSkin and maleSkins[skinIndex + 1] or femaleSkins[skinIndex + 1]
elseif source == createChar.prevSkin then
  newModel = maleSkin and maleSkins[skinIndex - 1] or femaleSkins[skinIndex - 1]
end
```

But you have to beware of `skinIndex` < 1 or > `#maleSkins`/`#femaleSkins`

Comment: No, please don't. Global vars are the root of all evil and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Hey, thanks! This actually gave me what I needed to get going. I was unable to get it working using maleSkins[skinIndex + 1] or maleSkins[skinIndex - 1] so I actually broke it apart doing skinIndex = skinIndex + 1 and then called the skinIndex inside the table call and it worked flawlessly!

Comment: This option doesn't wrap around the ends of the table either though, so if you want that, you'll still have to use the modulo operator :)